# How does an electron manage to constantly revolve around the nucleus of an atom forever?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics

When an electron revolves around the nucleus of an atom is it using any energy  in doing so. If so, where does this energy come from and how does it be a constant source (the electron revolves forever)? What is the energy being used and how is it not getting over?

Comment: This is the question that led to quantum mechanics. The short answer is "no it uses no energy to remain in its orbit".

Comment: @Floris Oh sorry for that. So how does it manage to keep revolving if it doesn't use up any energy? My apologies if this irritated you.

Comment: Not irritated at all. It is a very deep question. The answer is that you cannot explain this without moving away from the concept of a particle "orbiting" - the classical electron must radiate and lose energy but that is not what happens. This led to a fundamental rethinking of physics.

Comment: Be aware that, for example, the ground state for hydrogen has zero angular momentum.  Indeed, on the Bohmian interpretation, an S state electron is stationary.  http://www.bohmian-mechanics.net/whatisbm_pictures_hydrogen.html

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: stationary or just moving in a straight line through the nucleus?

Comment: @SuperCiocia: stationary.